# Boot and Install Windows 10 using grub

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-10

Currently I have installed Manjaro, but have access to GRUB before loading the OS, my USB is recognized, but it won't boot from it, even if I manually select it.

I've tried using different programs on another Windows machine to make the USB bootable with Windows and tried 4 ISOs using different partition types (MBR/GPT) and it still won't boot from it. I thought of fully resetting the BIOS, but I can't do it since my laptop (Innjoo Leapbook M100) doesn't have a CMOS battery and frankly, I don't think it's necessary since if I put Manjaro on a USB again, I can fully boot and install it, so it works fine.

Things I've tried to make it boot from the USB:

- Format the drive in FAT32 and put a W7 on it. It recognizes it, but it still won't boot from it.
- I tried the "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" and the format for my W10 .iso auto-changes to FAT32, but the same thing happens as in W7.
- I've also tried Unetbootin, Universal USB Installer and Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool.
- I've tried to put W10 and W7 using Rufus as well.
- If I use NTFS format for W10 using Rufus, it doesn't recognize it, therefor it doesn't boot from it.
- I tried putting the W10 using `DD` on Manjaro. It still wouldn't recognize it.
- The last thing I tried is putting the W10 on a USB with the official W10 tool from Microsoft that downloads and puts it on the USB. It recognizes it, but it still won't boot so I can install it.

Additional information:

- When I was installing Manjaro, I had to use Rufus with the DD Image option.
- My BIOS has only 3 tabs: "Main", "Boot" and "Save and Exit" (Aptio Setup Utility - American Megatrends). There is no way to set up things like "Legacy mode", nor is the "Fast boot" option enabled.

I found [this](http://blog.viktorpetersson.com/post/93191892924/how-to-boot-from-usb-with-grub2), but I don't know how to do it for a Windows. How do I do that (using GRUB 2.02)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From grub type: `ls` (that is an L) to list your devices.

Assuming that your USB shows up as (hd1) and there is only 1 partition type:
`chainloader (hd1,1)+1`
`boot`

Comment: When I type `ls`, I get `(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (hd2) (hd3)`. I'm assuming `(hd0,msdos1)` is my USB containing the W10.

Would this be correct `chainloader (hd0,msdos1)+1` and then `boot` ?

I'd try it myself, but I don't want to mess it up since I not very good with Linux, let alone GRUB, I figured it'd be safer to ask first.

Comment: yes, that would be the way

Comment: OK. Will try that. Should I still install `vmlinuz` and `initrd` somehow or do they come installed? If I only put `chainloader (hd0,msdos1)+1` I get an error saying "invalid EFI file path".

Comment: that is your boot error,  is there an efi folder on it? you need an efi version of windows installer  vmlinuz and initrd.img are for linux booting

Comment: On the USB? If, so, then Yes. It's in "/efi/boot/bootia32.efi".
I was thinking, am I supposed to put "chainloader (hd0,msdos1)+1 root=/efi/boot"? or "chainloader (hd0,msdos1)+1 root=/dev/sda/sda1/efi/boot"? Also, there's a file called "bootmgr.efi" in the main folder outside of everything on the USB.

Comment: you have a 32 bit installer, is the computer 64 bit? chainloader takes care of that

Comment: Yes, the computer is 64bit.

Comment: theoretically 32-bit can run on 64-bit systems but, your EFI implementation  may force you to get a 64-bit installer, it is looking for /efi/boot/bootx64.efi

Comment: Would it give me some sort of error or message that it's required to be a 64 bit installer?

Comment: nope just ignores it as not bootable

Comment: That's unfortunate. Can I force it to take the 32 bit or should I get the 64 bit? I wanted to get the 32 bit hoping that it would use less RAM.

Comment: considering the benefits of 64-bit, I'd look for a 64-bit EFI installer, should be easier to find that the 32-bit efi installer was

Comment: OK. I'll do that and post the results.

Comment: I just tried with the 64 bit and I got the same error ("invalid EFI file path") and I do have the "bootx64.efi" file in the "/efi/boot" folder.

Comment: try chainloader (hd0,1)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi  (note: it may be case sensitive)

Comment: You won't believe it, but I won't have to. I setup the boot order for the Nth time in the BIOS and this time, it booted the Windows x64 bit installer from the USB! Will be installing it now. Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart for sparing time to help me out. <3

Comment: no problem, you may have to set grub up again after installing. turn off fast boot and hibernate inside windows after it is installed

Comment: I would like to echo @DoombringerBG 's sentiments and also thank you @ravery . I spent some tens of hours working trying to get an old Mac booting Ubuntu again from a USB, with no progress. The problem was that the "Install Ubuntu" option to boot was not appearing after the post-Bios boot options. I tried everything with Grub2 to make it boot from the USB. For clarity, what finally worked was: 1) `set root='hd[something],[some partition]' ` 2) `chainloader (hd0,1)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi` # crux move by @ravery 3) `boot`, and the Installer appeared on the boot menu!

Comment: Note that the error I was getting was something like "error: invalid EFI file path" after `chainloader +1`. Step 2 of my previous comment fixed the problem.

Comment: I get an error: you need to load the kernel first. I'm trying to load a 32 bit Windows USB installer.