# Can't boot from usb even though I set my boot priority to usb

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, bios

so currently I'm having manjaro xfce installed now I need to install xubuntu over it. The problem is I can't access my bios with my bios key. Somehow I managed to boot into bios and set my usb as top priority but it won't boot from usb instead it boots manjari. If anyone has any idea please ping me thank you guys.

Comment: 1. Please tell us about your computer: brand name and model; 2. Please tell us how you created your Xubuntu live drive (version of Xubuntu, tool to create the live drive). -- Otherwise it is difficult to help (we can only guess).

Comment: Acer aspire E1-470p, used etcher to burn xubuntu

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932999/boot-and-install-windows-10-using-grub can someone explain this?

Comment: I have no own experience of Acer computers. Etcher has a good reputation. Let us hope that someone who knows how to boot an Acer computer from USB can chip in and help you.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932999/boot-and-install-windows-10-using-grub this guide solved the problem.

Comment: It may help other users if *you* describe the details, that you used to solve your problem. If short, you can do it in a comment, otherwise you can answer your own question (write an answer and 'accept' it by clicking on the tick icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority) and [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208417)