# Can't Boot USB via GRUB or BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, usb-installation

I've been having issues booting from a USB to reinstall windows (or any OS for that matter). I've got my BIOS set up correctly according to the Manufacturer (It's the legacy BIOS version with settings correct to [ASUS BOOT FROM USB SETTINGS](https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1013017/)).

I've also attempted to boot via grub using the command lines mentioned in this other AskUbuntu stack forum ([Stack Exchange - Boot USB from Grub 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100858/how-to-boot-to-usb-from-grub2-when-the-bios-keep-booting-solely-to-grub-despite)) but when I follow this it says no valid efi file. I know the USB should be correct, I've tried multiple USB's multiple OS's and i've even gone as far as to try all variants of the MBR/GPT and BIOS/UEFI options in rufus despite Ubuntu command line telling me it is GPT and the bios saying it can run Shell efi (I may be confused by the BIOS UEFI difference but regardless, I've tried both to no avail.)

If I use the BIOS's override function it won't boot the USB it just goes back to the BIOS after a quick black flicker and if I change boot order in BIOS it goes to some kind of bootloop (I think it's trying to boot to GRUB when it does this but I could be wrong, in this case I have to go back to BIOS and override boot back to ubuntu)

Ubuntu was installed via USB and is the lubuntu variant although I don't think that matters unless it cocked up the GRUB installation?

Could this be a damaged GRUB installation? One thing to note (although maybe unrelated) I lost all audio output when Installing Lubuntu so something definitely doesn't communicate or is missing somewhere. Is there another way I can get the thing to boot my windows USB?

EDIT: sidenote, one of the USBs I'm using was actually made with the windows 10 usb tool on the microsoft site and also doesn't work so even if I cocked up with rufus, that one 'should' work?

Edit: Followed instructions[Grub2 Boot+Install Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932999/boot-and-install-windows-10-using-grub)

```
grub>chainloader (hd0,gpt1)/efi/boot/bootia32.efi
grub>boot
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Comment: Systems since 2012 are UEFI, even though many vendors confusingly still call it BIOS. If UEFI system, you need to install in UEFI boot mode. And you do not boot flash drive from grub, but from UEFI boot menu.What model Asus? What video card/chip? Does it have Optane? If newer system may be similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279496/hard-time-installing-ubuntu-20-04-as-dual-boot-on-asus-rog-strix-g17

Comment: I've been able to get it to read an NTFS formatted stick so that was part of the problem, it's still failing to find the .efi file even though it's their. It would read another lubuntu stick formatted in NTFS with GPT and UFEI/BIOS settings but it only works with the Ubuntu copy. I think there's gotta be a grub issue but I don't know enough about grub. Gonna try a fresh Lubuntu install later (because that should do a fresh grub install, right?)

Comment: External devices boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in a FAT32 partition flagged as esp/boot. In UEFI boot menu it may show as UEFI:flash where flash is name or label of the flash drive or external device. Installer must be FAT32 and as ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: It shows as a hp drive or Sandisk drive dependent on which I use it shows literally by the brand/model of stick. Also if you're saying it boots from a FAT32 partition then that would explain the dual partitions on the stick I formatted to NTFS one of which does, as you say, contain the boot efi stuff. when booting that stick , as much as it does now boot it claims to not find the boot efi stuff. so I just end up stuck on a black text console ( is this console part of grub?)

Comment: i'll try to edit the question and upload pictures to better explain

Comment: If you move the .efi files & folders to the FAT32 and it is flagged as esp (if using gparted). Not sure if then you can find other files.  If manually installing grub, you also have to manually create a grub boot stanza. Only when part of an install does the installer create a grub boot stanza.  Or if an installer it will have a simiple grub.cfg to boot install medai. Not sure how Windows works. But newer Windows has a .wim that is too large for FAT32, so Windows tools split .wim file into 2, so installer  can be all in FAT32 partition.

Comment: I've continued my research and brainache and followed the steps mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/questions/932999/boot-and-install-windows-10-using-grub and got the same issue as the last comment, "you need to load kernel first" It's a single boot system I don't know if any of the lubuntu gear changes the kernel but maybe I've been doing the complete wrong thing? Maybe I need to install a kernel for windows? I think it may have finally gotten too complicated for me

Comment: To save any extra reading I've basically gone to grub command line > used command ls to list and identify the correct drive > used command "chainloader (hd0,gpt1)/efi/boot/bootia32.efi > command boot > grub returned "error:you need to load kernel first"

Comment: :Your bootia32.efi only applies to a limited number of 32 bit boot systems, that may still be 64 bit. And if you are getting grub you already have booted grub, but /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg or /boot/grub/grub.cfg have wrong UUID. Often easiest to just reinstall grub either full chroot or with Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Took mle took e a while to get round to it but here is the pastebin link http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gzPRvpXdDv/

Comment: Boot-Repair reinstalled grub and your MMC drive which is small looks normal.

Comment: The whole pc is small lol it's an ASUS e200h. I did some more digging and foundout its a 64 bit processor (which begs the question why they only do a 2gb ram model of this but hey ho). Could it cause an issue me tryng to install a 32bit windows? Also I realised I'm still on a 4.x.x kernel so gonna update that and see if that helps